# Changing width in my css class depending on the number of total iterations

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I hope you all have a nice evening.

I am currently making my personal blog in PHP with the CodeIgniter framework and bootstrap. On the frontpage I'm making a "recent blogposts" section with max 3 entries, and I would like to make it so that if I only have 1 blogpost, the width of the box is set to 66, if I have 2 blogposts the width is set to 33, and if I have 3 the width is set to 22. right now it iterates through a for each loop and making a box with the same size for every iteration.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$width = 22.3;
foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 float-left"
         style="width: <?php echo ($width) ?>rem;margin-left: 10px;">
        <div class="card-header"><?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> <i class="em em-memo" style="float:right;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?php

                if (strlen($post['body']) <= 150) {
                    echo $post['body'];
                } else {
                    $y = substr($post['body'], 0, 150) . '...';
                    echo $y;
                }

                ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/' . $post['slug']); ?>" role="button">Læs
                mere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php if ($i++ == 3) break; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope that I've explained my situation good enough :P. 
And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `count()` to check the number of posts and a few if's (using the shorthand `?:` in this case) to turn it into a width...

```
$numberPosts = count($posts);
$width = ($numberPosts==1)?66:(($numberPosts==2)?33:22);
```

Answer (score 0):

use count function available in php...

```
    if(count($posts) == 2 ){
    // foreach with class you want for 2 element
    }

else if (count($posts) == 3 ){
// foreach with class you want for 3 element
}
```

and so on ... thn if you need else condition in any other case